# How to fix the axios error 403 and 429 in react?

Tags: reactjs, error-handling, axios, get

I want to develop estate app with react using this api -- > [rest api link](https://rapidapi.com/apidojo/api/bayut/). But I get a 403 and 429 error when I fetch the api. How can I solve this problem? Or how to use the better get method?
Note that I have shared the codes and error img  below.

```js
import axios from "axios";

export const baseUrl = "https://bayut.p.rapidapi.com";

export const fetchApi = async (url) => {
  const { data } = await axios.get(url, {
    headers: {
      "x-rapidapi-host": "bayut.p.rapidapi.com",
      "x-rapidapi-key": "api-key",
    },
  });

  return data;
};



import { baseUrl, fetchApi } from "../../utils/fetchApi";

  useEffect(() => {
    const propertyForSale = fetchApi(
      `${baseUrl}/properties/list?locationExternalIDs=5002&purpose=for-sale&hitsPerPage=6`
    );
    console.log(propertyForSale);
  }, []);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

[image: error img]